# Using WinForms on Mono 3 (Ubuntu 12.10)

Tags: c#, linux, winforms, ubuntu, mono

I am looking to start a project that uses C# & WinForms. I want to develop it with Mono 3.0.3.2 on Ubuntu but it seems like `System.Drawing` and `System.Windows.Forms` can't be resolved. I have `libgdiplus` installed, as it is needed.

The error is "Resolve error" when I hover over one of the using statements.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, after a bit of determined digging I found the solution :

- Double-click `References` folder in the Solution browser
- Tick the needed libraries (`Windows.Forms` & `Drawing`)